Do I use [Authorize] annotation?
I have a web application in which you can register with the given data (username, password). Then a JWT token is built using this data and stored in the session using the jwt-token key. Also I have for example the main page of my application, I want an authorized user to be able to go to this resource using only a query input in the browser. Here is my code:
app.MapGet("/home", [Authorize]() => {
    // return my page
});

But to go to such a resource in the request must specify Authorization header with jwt token, it turns out that just writing in the browser “www.mywebsite/home” will not be able to go to the page /home because I did not pass this header, I solved this problem by adding jwt token in the session and when going to the page /home check its presence and correctness.
So my question is, should I use the [Authorize] annotation in my case, or what did I do wrong?

You could use:
app.MapGet("/home", () => {
    // return my page
}).RequireAuthorization();

Have a look in the docs for more details (including JWT).


So my question is, should I use the [Authorize] annotation in my case, or what did I do wrong?

This is according to your requirement, as you said I want an authorized user to be able to go to this resource using only a query input in the browser.
If this page, you need user type in something, need get the username and only login in user could access, then you must use [Authorize] annotation which makes only login in user could access it.
Since if the request contains the JWT token, after decoded the JWT token, the server could know the username or some user information from this token which could let you write the role permission or else to protect the resources inside your application.

See to go to the resource with the annotation [Authorize] you need to specify the header “Authorization” in the headers and only then the resource will return the page otherwise there will be an error 401 Unauthorized, it turns out to enter such a resource must use Javascript in my application, this is not a problem but I also want to be able to go to the page without writing additional headers
